# Follow / Unfollow Database Schema for Groups or Lists

Tags: mysql, database, data-structures, structure

What I'm looking to create is a follower / following system where instead of simply following a user, you're following sections of content they share. Almost as if you were following Twitter's "Lists" or Groups rather than the people. Though, with this you'd be able follow/unfollow everything a user is sharing or just follow/unfollow the lists that you want.

**Ex #1:** I click a "follow all" button to follow *User #1's* lists but unfollow the one about politics. Now I'm following all of what they are sharing except one list. I am a follower of them.

**Ex #2:** I follow only one of *User #2's* lists instead of clicking the "follow all" button. I should only see the one list and not all of their lists.

The structure for a simple follow/following system may be a table with `user_id => follower_id` schema, but that wouldn't account for the new lists created by the user that one follows.

**Question: What database schema would suit this best?**

Comment: You'd need some kind of meta system here I think in addition to the basic linkages table that stores follower => followed. A publish/subscriber setup. This could then store follower => publisher . When publisher adds a new list it broadcasts a message to the follower set in that meta table and creates a new row for all followers subscribed to them.

Comment: @PorridgeBear I thought about that, but it seems like there has to be a simpler solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To simplify it and to help it scale, I would think of it as a mapping of `list_id => follower_id` with a helper table that is a mapping of `user_id => follower_id`

The only thing the helper table would let you know is that if the user creates a new list, it tells you what `list_id => follower_id` mappings you need to create. It basically just serves as a setting for the follower. (Ex: Automatically follow X user's new lists)

When you are displaying the feed to the follower you would only access the table that has the map `list_id => follower_id`. You wouldn't even need to look up the `user_id => follower_id` mapping. That only comes in to play when a new list is created.

The biggest problem here is that you have to handle the case where the follower says "Follow All"/"Follow User" for the first time. In this case you would backfill all of the `list_id => follower_id` mappings based on what lists already exist for that user. (I believe this is similar to how Twitter handles their following model. If I start to follow someone it backfills an X number of their tweets and if I unfollow it removes an X number of their most recent tweets)

Then, if the user wants to exclude a list, you just remove the mapping for that specific list to that follower. You can leave the mapping of `user_id => follower_id` in this case because I'm assuming you want any new lists the user creates to show up for the follower.

Comment: If you wanted to count them as a follower, you could make the `user_id => follower_id` exist if the follower is following any of the user's lists and put an extra field on there that says auto_follow is true or false for the case where they want to auto follow any new lists the user creates. Then when the user creates a new list, look up all followers that have set auto_follow to true and insert the `list_id => follower_id` mapping at that time.

Comment: I wonder at what point would that become just a monster size table? It seems even with 100k users @10 lists a piece and following an average of 100 people there would be a ton of rows.

Comment: Yeah, it can be a lot of data, but storage is cheap, and if you get 100K active users then you can get funding to buy more storage :) The most important part of this design is making sure that reads are fast, even if it means you store more data. The nice thing with this approach is that reads should basically be just as fast with one user as with a million users and the schema is simple. Either way, hope this helps. I'm out of other ideas. We use a similar following strategy with our product, but it's with a non-relational database so it might not apply exactly to MySQL.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Greatly appreciated. Are you able to talk about how it's done on a system such as yours?